# Kaprekar's Routine - Haskell Implementation

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, subroutine

I am having a little trouble with Haskell. I am doing an implemenation of Kaprekar's routine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_%28number%29) and I have done everything but being able to successfully print the list of numbers that the routine produces. So, if I put in the number 5432, I would like the output to be [5432, 3087, 8352, 6174].

Here is the code I have:

```
kaprekarList :: Integer -> [Integer]

kaprekarList x = n
  where p = kaprekar x
        n =
          if p == 6174
              then [p]
              else
                -- add to list of kaprekar numbers
                kaprekarList p
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How have you defined `kaprekar` and what's the output you are actually getting with the current implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not the most beautiful routine (and having a small problem see below) yours seems to work (if the `kaprekar` function does), so I guess your problem is really there.

Here is a simple implementation together with your function:

```
kaprekar :: Integer -> Integer
kaprekar n = big - small
  where big = read digits
        small = read (reverse digits)
        digits = take 4 $ (reverse . sort . show $ n) ++ "0000"

kaprekarList :: Integer -> [Integer]
kaprekarList x = n
  where p = kaprekar x
        n =
          if p == 6174
              then [x, p]
              else
                -- add to list of kaprekar numbers
                x : kaprekarList p
```

Please mind the small changes so that you can see the complete *derivation* instead of just the last element (that is always fixed).

#### alternative versions

```
kaprekarList :: Integer -> [Integer]
kaprekarList x = x : if x == 6174 then [] else kaprekarList (kaprekar x)
```

this one seems to be a bit more idiomatic but will not include the last 6174

```
kaprekarList :: Integer -> [Integer]
kaprekarList x = takeWhile (/= 6174) $ iterate kaprekar x
```

this one will (but is ugly - maybe someone knows something like `takeUntil` in the prelude?):

```
kaprekarList :: Integer -> [Integer]
kaprekarList x = (takeWhile (/= 6174) $ iterate kaprekar x) ++ [6174]
```

Comment: Thank you @Carsten König! It looks like I did everything write but the [x, p] part. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here an implementation:

```
import Data.List (sort)

-- Convert a number to a list of digits
digits :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digits 0 = []
digits x = digits (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]

-- Convert a list of digits to a number
undigits :: Integral x => [x] -> x
undigits = foldl (\ a b -> a * 10 + b) 0

-- Compute the next Kaprekar number
nextKapNumber :: Integral x => x -> x
nextKapNumber x = b - a
  where n = sort . digits $ x
        a = undigits n
        b = undigits . reverse $ n

-- Compute the Kaprekar list for a number
kapList :: Integral x => x -> [x]
kapList x = genList [x]
  where genList as@(6174:_) = reverse as
        genList as@(a:_)    = genList $ nextKapNumber a : as

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ kapList 5432
```